# How to compress dataframes in RAM in R /pandas?

Tags: r, pandas, memory-management, dataframe, bigdata

I have a csv file of size 3.8gb. But when i zipped the csv the files size reduced to just 60 mb! I also have only 6gb RAM.

Is there anyway in R /pandas to compress the dataframe in RAM so that the dataframe will only occupy just 60 mb instead of 3.8 gb? Thus the software becoming more memory efficient?

If this feature is available then how to do this in R and pandas?

Comment: Without knowing the format of your csv files this question is hard to answer. Yes, you can probably use much less RAM than the 3.8gb text file - No you cannot use the same strategies as you would apply to a file on your disk. On the disk you only have to store the information, in memory you often have to keep this information in a form which is easy to manipulate.

Comment: It may be more memory efficient but I doubt it will be more processing efficient as it'll have to decompress the data and recompress no?

Comment: I got your point. For me ram size is bigger constraint than computation time. So given this can i still achieve this compression at cost if run time?